# HTML modal-dialog box does not load properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to add a modalbox on a href click in html. 
The code for HTML is :

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">

</div>
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS that I had applied to my dialog box :

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-front {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

As expected, on clicking the 'Model Open' link I should be able to see a modal pop-up with body inside it. 
However, my screen appears like an open modal without any body in it (No body contents and close icon).

See the attached image . It shows how the modal looks on opening. The background is disabled as it should be.
[image]

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted has two links with the same ID. Perhaps that was a typo, but if not, IDs must be unique. I couldn't replicate the issue. Your code seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/reqwptnx/

Comment: A sad and very bad typo that was @Cory.
Thanks a lot for rectifying it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have an empty container with the same id opening up
If you remove the following empty div it works fine

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">

</div>
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6zn93ze/1/

Comment: Thanks Nick..
A simple error like this consumed my hour .